# On click anywhere close slide menu

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am using a Blueprint Slide and Push Menus but the problem is i need the menu to be close when click any part of the body except menu.

Please help me. I need the code. 
http://tympanus.net/Blueprints/SlidePushMenus/

Comment: What you'll have to do is add a listener to the click event. When the currentTarget of that click event is not the menu, and the menu is open, close it.

Comment: http://chris-spittles.co.uk/jquery-close-menu-clicking-document/

Answer (score 1):

This may help you.

```
$(document).click(function(){
    if($('yourElement').is(':visible')){
        $('yourElement').slideUp(300);
    }
});

$("yourElement").on('click',function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to catch click on your document:

```
$('html').click(function(event)
{

    // Then find a target: element you clicked on.

    var target = $(event.target);

    // Close your sidebar only if you clicked outside of this sidebar:

    if (target.closest('#id-of-sidebar').length === 0) {
        $('#id-of-sidebar').hide(); // or else special hide method.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).click(function(event){ 
    if(document.activeElement.nodeName=='BODY'){ 
        $("your menu selector").hide(); 
    }; 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

### Use the following code :

```
 $(document.body).bind("click", function(e) {
    $(".selector")).hide();
 });
```